# How can i convert this format string to CSV?

Tags: linux, perl, awk

my string is:

```
AA:: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
BB:: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
C: ccccccccccccccccc
DD:: DDDDDDDDDDDD
E: EEEEEEEEEEEEE

AA: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2
BB:: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb2
C:: ccccccccccccccccc2
DD: DDDDDDDDDDDD2
E: EEEEEEEEEEEEE

....
```

i need get this format with standard linux command like awk or ... or perl function

```
AA,BB,C,DD,E
aaaaaaaa,bbbbbb,ccccc,dddddd,eeeee
aaaaaaaa2,bbbbbb2,ccccc2,dddddd2,eeeee2
```

> exm:
>  OUTPUT_STRING | awk .... 
>   or 
>  perlFunction(OUTPUT_STRING){ 
> .....
>   return formated_string;
>  }

**i searched google and try many help on more site and not work, so dont send me a link**

some field have **single :** and some field have **double :** (this is random)

i try some help and not worked for me

`sed -r 's/\\,|,|CN=|OU*//g' |awk -F "|=|:" '{printf $2"|"}'`
 or 
`sed -n '1h; 2,$H;${g;s/\n/,/g;p}' | sed 's/,,/\n/g'`
 or 
`awk -F ":" '{printf $2} {if (NF==0) {printf "\n"}}' | sed "s/ //" | sed "s/ /;/g"`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: @nibkuz, Kindly place this attempt in your question, as comments are not meant for mentioning them, kindly edit your question and add this there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `gnu awk` should do:

```
awk -v RS='' -F':* ?|\n' 'NR==1{print $1","$3","$5","$7","$9} {print $2","$4","$6","$8","$10}' t
AA,BB,C,DD,E
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,ccccccccccccccccc,DDDDDDDDDDDD,EEEEEEEEEEEEE
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb2,ccccccccccccccccc2,DDDDDDDDDDDD2,EEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

- `RS=''` set record selector to nothing so awk works in block mode.
- `-F':* ?|\n'`  Sets field separator to `:` or `::` or newline
- `NR==1{print $1","$3","$5","$7","$9}` for first line print the header
- `{print $2","$4","$6","$8","$10}` print the data fields.

---

A more generic solution that should work with more fields:

```
awk -v RS='' -F':* ?|\n' 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF-2;i+=2) printf "%s,",$i;print $i} {for(i=2;i<=NF-2;i+=2) printf "%s,",$i;print $i}' file
AA,BB,C,DD,E
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,ccccccccccccccccc,DDDDDDDDDDDD,EEEEEEEEEEEEE
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb2,ccccccccccccccccc2,DDDDDDDDDDDD2,EEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

PS If not all record have all ID, then its an whole other story to program.

Answer (score 4):

One of many ways to achieve desired result

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = do { local $/; <DATA> };         # read whole file
my @blocks = split /\n\n/, $file;           # split file into blocks

my $print_header = 1;                       # flag to print header

foreach my $block (@blocks) {               # process each block
    $block =~ s/:+/:/g;                     # clean up the block :: -> :

    my @lines = split /\n/, $block;         # split the block into lines
    my(@header,@data);                      # arrays to store header and data

    foreach my $line (@lines) {             # process each line
        my($h,$d) = split /:\s*/, $line;    # split line into header and data part
        push @header, $h;                   # add header names into array
        push @data, $d;                     # add data into array
    }

    if( $print_header ){                    # if header not printed yet
        print join(',', @header) . "\n";    # print header array
        $print_header = 0;                  # flag the header is printed 
    }

    print join(',', @data)   . "\n";        # print data array
}

__DATA__
AA:: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
BB:: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
C: ccccccccccccccccc
DD:: DDDDDDDDDDDD
E: EEEEEEEEEEEEE

AA: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2
BB:: bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb2
C:: ccccccccccccccccc2
DD: DDDDDDDDDDDD2
E: EEEEEEEEEEEEE2
```

output

```
AA,BB,C,DD,E
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,ccccccccccccccccc,DDDDDDDDDDDD,EEEEEEEEEEEEE
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb2,ccccccccccccccccc2,DDDDDDDDDDDD2,EEEEEEEEEEEEE2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) to handle [edge cases](http://thomasburette.com/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV 'csv';

my $input = do { local $/; readline }; # input from STDIN or filename argument

my @aoh;
my %headers;
foreach my $block (split /\n\n+/, $input) {
  my %row;
  foreach my $line (split /^/, $block) {
    if ($line =~ m/^([^:]+):+\s*(.*)$/) {
      $row{$1} = $2;
      $headers{$1} = 1;
    }
  }
  push @aoh, \%row;
}

csv(in => \@aoh, out => *STDOUT, headers => [sort keys %headers],
  encoding => 'UTF-8', auto_diag => 2);
```